# Type hint for numpy.ndarray containing unsignedinteger

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I have a numpy array that contains unsignedinteger, something like this:

```
arr = np.uint16([5, 100, 2000])

array([   5,  100, 2000], dtype=uint16)
```

This `arr` will be input to a function. I am wondering how the type hint of the function argument should look like?

```
def myfunc(arr: ?):
    pass
```

I was first thinking it should be `arr: np.ndarray`. But then `mypy` is complaining.
`Argument "arr" to "myfunc" has incompatible type "unsignedinteger[_16Bit]"; expected "ndarray[Any, Any]"  [arg-type]`

Neither does `arr: np.ndarray[np.uint16]` work.
`error: "ndarray" expects 2 type arguments, but 1 given  [type-arg]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`typing`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html) module from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def myfunc(arr: npt.NDArray[np.int16]):
    pass
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Having said that, it is only working if I define ``arr`` as follows: ``arr = np.array([5, 100, 2000], dtype=np.uint16)``.

Answer (score 0):

The NumPy documentation has you covered. You are looking for `numpy.typing.NDArray`:

```
from numpy import typing as npt

def myfunc(arr: npt.NDArray):
    pass
```

Comment: This is the generic way to do it if you don't want to worry about type conversions like in the accepted answer.